# How to implement custom text encoding in Android?

Tags: java, android, fonts, character-encoding

I want to display a language (other than English) with my own text encoding/decoding methods.
I have my database in binary, where each letter is represented as 16-bit.
I also have the information available for the charset mapping.

Problem is there are some extra letters than the standard unicode can show.
So I want to write my own character encoding/decoding methods.
I also want to design my own font for the character mapping.

How should I approach this in Android app?

Answer (score 0):

### How to add a custom charset

How to add a custom charset is contained in the book [Java NIO](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-nio/0596002882/) by Ron Hitchens. You can download [sample of Charset and CharsetProvider](http://www.javanio.info/filearea/bookexamples/unpacked/com/ronsoft/books/nio/charset/) from [the support site](http://www.javanio.info). Note that you have to make a file [META-INF/services/java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider](http://ww.javanio.info/filearea/bookexamples/unpacked/META-INF/services/java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider) that contains the FQCN of the additional `CharsetProvider` and put it into the `jar` you will make.

You might use a code in https://stackoverflow.com/a/38768564/3902663 on the CustomCharsetProvider.

### How to make a custom font file

You can make a `.ttf` file coordinated to the custom charset with some font editor, like [FontForge](https://fontforge.org/en-US/) or [Birdfont](https://birdfont.org/).

### How to add a custom font file into the app

I am unfamiliar with native Android applications, but it seems like you can use [Calligraphy](https://github.com/InflationX/Calligraphy) to use the additional font in Android applications.